# Retrieving DHCP options in Android

Tags: android, dhcp

How can I get the DHCP options (like TFTP server name, option 66) from the Android API? The `DhcpInfo` class doesn't have any info on the DHCP extensions.

Comment: You may want to check out [EMDK for Android](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/4-0/mx/dhcp/) which allows you to configure DHCP options.

Comment: Looks promising, thanks. Is it free and can I include the SDK in a business app?